# Why the for loop is not working?when i enter the values

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Here is code.I don't know what problem is.When i enter the values,the for loop is not working.
I am working on a problem ask me to:
find the two largest values among several integers.Assume that the first integer read specifies the number of values remaining to be entered.Thanks guys!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i, largest, secondLargest, temp;
cout << "Enter the number of integers to be processed followed by the integers:";
cin >> i;
cin >> largest;
cin >> secondLargest;

if (secondLargest > largest)            
{
    temp = secondLargest;
    secondLargest = largest;
    largest = temp;
}
for (int b; i > 1; i--)
{
    cin >> b;
    if (b > largest)
    {
        secondLargest = largest;
        largest = b;
    }
}
cout << "Largest is " << largest << endl << "Second largest is " << secondLargest << endl;

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger to find out, rather than asking here.

Comment: Just saying something "is not working" is not sufficient. You really have to tell us what you expected it to do, what it did, and what you tried to figure out why they differ.

Comment: this is not the best way to check enter key and process the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program and the loop works. At least nearly.

The only problem is, that the loop body gets executed `(i-1)` times instead of `(i-2)` times.

To fix this, you can change `i > 1` to `i > 2`.

edit:

Oh, and you additionally have to check, if `b` is between `largest` and `second_largest`. In that case you have the replace `second_largest` with `b`.

Comment: @Adi `i > 2` is the same thing as `i >= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop to

```
    for (int b; i > 2; i--)
```

The reason being is because you already ask for the first two integers at the top of the program, so you must take that into account. The loop will go from `i` which, lets just say I wanted to input 10 integers, will count until 3 then stop since you already asked for the Largest and secondLargest at the top:

```
Here's an example:
    cin >> i;
    cin >> largest
    cin >> secondLargest;

    For loop declared i = 10
    i = 9
    i = 8
    i = 7
    i = 6
    i = 5
    i = 4
    i = 3

Total integers asked for = 10
```

I hope this helps! Ask if you have questions!

Comment: I got it. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @T2Bee Cool. No problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i, largest, secondLargest, temp;
cout << "Enter the number of integers to be processed followed by the integers:";
cin >> i;
cin >> largest;
cin >> secondLargest;

if (secondLargest > largest)            
{
    temp = secondLargest;
    secondLargest = largest;
    largest = temp;
}
for (int b; i > 2; i--)
{
    cin >> b;

    if (b > largest)
    {
        secondLargest = largest;
        largest = b;
        b = 0;
    }
    if (b > secondLargest)
        secondLargest = b;
}
cout << "Largest is " << largest << endl << "Second largest is " << secondLargest << endl;

system("pause");

}
```